# Redis : How can I sort my hash by keys?

Tags: redis

Suppose that I have some news stored in a hash. I have different hashes (each hash represent one news) :

```
news:1
news:2
news:3
...
```

I want to retrieve all the keys with the KEYS command like that :

```
KEYS news:*
```

The problem the keys are not sorted :

```
news:3
news:1
news:2
```

I would like to retrieve the list of keys in the right order. I'm not sure that the hash is the structure that I need. But, according to the [redis documentation](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#hashes) :

> Redis Hashes are maps between string field and string values, so they are the perfect data type to represent objects (for instance Users with a number of fields like name, surname, age, and so forth):

Storing my news object in a hash seems to be a good idea.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: If you want the keys sorted, are you sure it's a hash and not a list you want?

Comment: @Theo, it's a part of my question. See below ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of Redis hashes as indexed documents.

```
HSET news:1 title levy_breaks
HSET news:1 type breaking_news
HSET news:1 byline alphazero
HSET news:1 date 04:25:2011
HSET news:1 content <the story>

HSET news:2 ...
..
```

In the above, `news:1` is the 'hash key', followed by a 'hash field' and finally its associated value.

That said, it seems you simply want to sort your 'hash keys'.

Use a `MULTI/EXEC` construct to set all the fields for a news item (which has n fields), and finally also add the hash key -- e.g. your news item -- it to a sorted set.  Alternatively, you can just add them to a list and use the `SORT` command on that list.

[The Redis docs](http://redis.io/commands).

Comment: Is it possible to detect when a key is added to my dictionary, then add this key to my sorted list ? Without that feature, how can I be sure that my sorted list contains the fully key in my hash at any time ? Thanks.

Comment: Redis does support pub/sub semantics.  So you could add a publish the news:xxx key (to "news:channel", for example) in the multi/exec block.  See http://redis.io/topics/pubsub. Do ask the redis google group as there is quite possibly a far more efficient to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is store a set or list of the news items that exist. For example, when you create a new news item, let's say `news:4`, you could add the index 4 to a set, say `list:news`, which would now have `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Now suppose your news hash structure is date, author. With this in place you could execute the following:

```
sort list:news get *->some_value_a ->*->some_value_b
```