# Redis - how to sort by hash field in redis as opposed to key?

Tags: redis

Let's suppose I want have redis hash `a = {1:10, 2:15, 3:5, 4:0, 5:20}`, and a set `b = (5,3,4)`. I want to get a list containing elements from `b`, sorted by values of `a[b]` (result in this case is `[4,3,5]`).

When I try to do this, it doesn't work well.

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> hmset a 1 10 2 15 3 5 4 0 5 20
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> sadd b 5 3 4
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> sort b by a->*
1) "3"
2) "4"
3) "5"
```

Obviously, asterisk in hash field placeholder doesn't work. Are there other ways beside declaring a:1-a:5 to do this task by means of Redis?

P.S. This is not a duplicate of [Redis : How can I sort my hash by keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780365/redis-how-can-i-sort-my-hash-by-keys), as that question clearly discusses the `a:*` approach.

Comment: this seems to be a known issue: [github](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/300)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a know issue: [link](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/300)

you could do the following:

redis 127.0.0.1:6379> sadd b 5 3 4

redis 127.0.0.1:6379> zadd a 10 1 15 2 5 3 0 4 20 5

redis 127.0.0.1:6379> zinterstore result 2 a b

redis 127.0.0.1:6379> zrange result 0 -1

1) "4"

2) "3"

3) "5"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can model it using sorted sets instead? Use the values as score, and the keys as members. Sorted sets are more or less like hashes sorted by value. I'd love to give you an example, but I'm not sure exactly what the problem you're trying to solve is. If you could elaborate maybe I could help.