# Is there a way to return a sorted key list from a hash?

Tags: redis

I'm new to redis and reading the documentation I'm not able to find a solution to my problem.

I have a hash with names and phone numbers and I would like to get the a sorted list of the keys in the hash.

So my hash (phonebook) looks like this:

```
 Andrew -> 9999
 Sam    -> 6666
 Eddy   -> 5555
```

If I run `hkeys phonebook` I get this (keys are returned as they are stored):

```
 Andrew
 Sam
 Eddy
```

And I would like to get this (ordered keys):

```
 Andrew
 Eddy
 Sam
```

How could I archive this? Am I using the correct data structure?

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780365/redis-how-can-i-sort-my-hash-by-keys

Comment: @SAFX So, as far as I can understand, I've to build a parallel list with the keys of the hash and then sort that list?

Comment: Found a better way to do it, see below, hope it helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a sorted set to achieve this, not a hash, and you don't need to maintain a parallel list; it's all contained in a single structure...

Populate the sorted set...

```
> zadd ss:phonebook 9999 Andrew
> zadd ss:phonebook 4444 Sam
> zadd ss:phonebook 3333 Bob
> zadd ss:phonebook 7777 Maria
> zadd ss:phonebook 8888 Sophia
```

Since `ss:phonebook` contains string values (the names), and you want to sort them lexicographically, use the ALPHA modifier:

```
> SORT ss:phonebook ALPHA
1) "Andrew"
2) "Bob"
3) "Maria"
4) "Sam"
5) "Sophia"
```

Hope it helps...