# How can I sort hset in Redis?

Tags: sorting, redis

I would to sort my data with point

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[4]> hset player1 point 2
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[4]> hset player1 level 5
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[4]> hset player2 point 1 
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[4]> hset player2 level 9
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[4]> hset player3 point 10
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[4]> hset player3 level 5
(integer) 1
```

Is there a way that return me a list in what way?

```
player3
player1
player2
```

Comment: i guess you have to use a SET. an HSET (hash set) is the wrong datastructure for sorting.

Comment: @fege Along the same lines, may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16449868/791406

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant sort `HSET` response in redis. But you can use [Redis sorted set](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set) instead of a hashmap:

```
ZADD players 2 player1
ZADD players 1 player2
ZADD players 10 player3
```

Now you can sort all your players by score:

```
ZREVRANGE players 0 -1
```

You can use both `HGET` and `ZREVRANGE` if you want to store additional data. So, you'll use `ZREVRANGE` to get the keys of best players and `GET`, `HGET` or `HGETALL` to get any additional data you need. But in this case you'll need to maintain both sorted set and hashmap:

```
HMSET player1 name Peter level 5
HMSET player2 name John level 9
HMSET player3 name Michael level 5
ZADD players 2 player1 1 player2 10 player3
```